# How to send a page's data to another page in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a php page in which a user enters form details..when the user clicks on search the user should be redirected to another page with the filtered values..

Comment: Set action of your form to your second page, receive and process data there and generate `filtered values`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Learn more about [http request methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) and [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 3):

you can try like this:

**search.php**

```
<form method="post" action="search_process.php">
Field 1: <input  type="text" name="f_1" /><br/>
Field 2: <input  type="text" name="f_2" /><br/>
Field 3: <input  type="text" name="f_3" /><br/>
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**search_process.php**

```
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
{
echo $_POST['f_1'] . '<br />';
echo $_POST['f_2'] . '<br />';
echo $_POST['f_3'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `method` to form `get/post` and `action` = to where you want to redirect..

```
 <form method="post" action="path\to\anotherrpage">  //say search.php
 <input type="test" name="search" />  
 //your fields

</form>
```

and you can the the values in another page (**search.php**) by

```
var searchedtext=$_POST['search']; // if your method is post
var searchedtext=$_GET['search']; // if your method is get
```

Answer (score 0):

you can submit the form using post or get method with the action to another php file for example named search.php.
In that file u need to do the search process and another thing the key to search

Answer (score 0):

Three ways

1. [POST](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp)

You can send data from one page to another as `$_POST` variables. Data will be hidden rom users.

1. [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)

You can send data from one page to another as `$_GET` variables. Data will be shown in URL link. By the same way you can pass data via url and get it in the next page too.

1. [SESSION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

You can get data anywhere in site using sessions.

The links describes well.